# Firebase/Android: Get current user email

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the email address of the current user.
I have the following code in my onCreate, but it isn't working:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        }
    }
};
```

Note that variable authListener at the top is "never used" according to my program. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. Does anyone know what could be wrong with the code I have above?

Comment: have you authenticate user using fire base authentication?

Comment: I actually just fixed it, thanks!

Comment: great happy to hear you that you find your solution

Comment: check out my helper class https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java

Comment: how can i get the current user ? see if the user had been signed up before .And to tell user that this email is used before ? how to reach this ?

Comment: I am working on this in Kotlin Lang

Answer (score 2):

Update, got it working! The below code gets the current users email.

```
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                String userEmail = user.getEmail();
            } else {
                // No user is signed in
            }
```

Comment: I want to get the user email to check if the user had been signed up before or not